# How do I render the response data from axios in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-state

I am using `axios` to get data from a url. I am then storing the fetched data in `post` using `setPost()`. Once the data is stored in `post`, I am then decoding the data using a function `getData()` which further assigns the decoded data to `metar` using `setMetar()`. The user enters data in an `input` and clicks on the `submit` button to get the decoded data. The problem is that it takes 2 clicks to get the decoded data instead of 1. Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer, useCallback } from "react";
import "./Search.css";
import axios from "axios";
import parseMETAR from "metar";

let dataList = "";

const Search = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
  
  const [icao, setIcao] = useState("");
  const [metar, setMetar] = useState("");
  

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(icao);
  }, []);

  const getData = (code) => {
    try {
      console.log(code);
      const url = `Some url`;
      console.log(url);
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        setPost(response.data);  
        getMetar();
      });
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };


  const getMetar = () => {
    // decode the raw text
    setMetar(mtr);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setIcao(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    getData(icao);
  };

  return (
    <div className="search-div">
      <h2>Search METAR</h2>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter ICAO"
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
        />
        <button onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>Get Metar</button>
      </form>

      <h3>METAR: {metar.length > 0 && metar}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

As soon as the button is clicked, the console shows the correct data stored in the `icao`. But, `metar`'s value is not rendered. How do I wait for `axios` to get the fetched data? If this is not a problem, how do I force the `Search` component to re render after the update functions of each `useState` variables?

Comment: i think it might be because how you are calling getMetar right after setPost in your getData function. My guess is that by the time you call getMetar, setPost hasn't done its job due to the fact that the component hasn't rerendered yet and there is no batching of useState hooks in an async functions...So, may be a trick would be to do getMetar(response.data) and use the response directly in your getMetar function, just to debugg and check if this is the problem

Comment: `useEffect(() => { getData(icao); }, []);` this effect doesn't rerun when `icao` changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setPost` is an asynchronous operation. And you are calling `getMetar()` right after it. As a result your first click is registering the payload and you are getting the data on second click. This way you are actually missing the data from 2nd api call. You will get the updated payload on your third click.

You can set a `useEffect` hook with `post` dependency. So when `post` get updated with the api data then you call `getMetar()`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getMetar();
  }, [post]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load data while the application is running, using the `useEffect` Hook is pretty simple.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
  getMetar();
},[post])
```