# Need to click twice to call the API React

Tags: reactjs

I have to click twice to call the API on the following function. each time I have to click twice.
i have added the async await too.

```
const [seatData, setSeateData] = React.useState([]);
const [seatPrice, setSeatPrices] = React.useState([]);

const showTimeHandleClicked = async(bookData,showDate) => {
  localStorage.setItem("venue","539")
  localStorage.setItem("movieDate",showDate.date)
  localStorage.setItem("showtime",bookData.showtimeId)
  localStorage.setItem("MovieShowtime", bookData.showtime)
  let mounted = true
  let pricemounted = true
  await GetSeatArrangement()
  .then(data =>{
    if(mounted){
      setSeateData(data?.data?.reservedSeats)
    }
})
  GetSeatPrices()
  .then(data => {
    if(pricemounted){
      setSeatPrices(data?.data?.ticketPrices)
      console.log("hi")
    }
  })
```

Comment: If you are talking about the ```console.log("hi")``` triggering before and then on next click you're getting the api response. Then it's because of ```setSeatPrices``` is asynchronous. I have answered a slimier question. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72505121/10413273

Comment: what's your react version?

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia "react": "^18.1.0"

Comment: if you are using react in `StrictMode` ,Disable it by deleting the `<React.StrictMode>`  component

Comment: @RakibUddin can i have updated as below

`React.useEffect(() => {
      let mounted = true;

      GetShowtimes()
      .then(data =>{
        if(mounted){
          setShowData(data?.data?.dateShowtimes)
        }
    },
    showTimeHandleClicked()
    )
    return () => {
      mounted = false
    }
    },[seatData])`

it shows React Hook React.useEffect has a missing dependency

Comment: @RyanFonseka No need to change the above code. Just use this ```React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(seatData);
}, [seatData])```

Comment: @RakibUddin still the same. can you please provide this as an answer?